# Rename callback parameter for JSONP

Tags: jsonp, servicestack

Is there a way to rename the query string parameter that holds the name of callback function? Say, I've got a legacy app which sources I can't access, I want it to be switched to ServiceStack, but the app uses "function" query string parameter, while SS expects "callback".

Comment: why do you think it uses function? can you post an example.

Comment: @mythz: sorry for my English. I meant that old app uses "function", but SS uses "callback". I'll update the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a response filter, inside `AppHost.Configure()`:

```
ResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
    {
        var func = req.QueryString.Get("function");
        if (!func.isNullOrEmpty())
        {
            res.AddHeader("Content-Type", ContentType.Html);
            res.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>{0}({1});</script>"
                .FormatWith(func, dto.ToJson()));
            res.Close();
        }
    });
```